# How can i target a specific containers within a container to change the background color?

Tags: html, css

Hi guys!

 Im new to the community as to HTML and CSS.

Im building a website that has 5 cards:

- 1st card has one container with an image left and a paragraph right
- 2nd card is divided in two containers with a paragraph left and image right
- 3rd card is divided in two containers with a image left and paragraph right
- 4th card has one container with an image left and a paragraph left and image right
- 5th card has one container with a centered paragraph

```css
#home {
      &-a {
        .card {
          &-container {
            display: flex;
            background: $main-color;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 5rem 1rem;
            padding: 0.5rem;

            .text-wrapper {
              width: 150%;
            }

            &:nth-child(4) {
              background: $secondary-color;
            }

            &-split {
              display: flex;
              margin: 5rem 1rem;
              height: auto;
            }

            &-text {
              background: $secondary-color;
              box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
              margin-right: 2rem;
              width: 300%;
            }

            &-image {
              background: $secondary-color;
              box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
              padding: 0.5rem;
            }
          }
        }

        .image-wrapper {
          background: $dark-color;
          padding: 3rem;
        }

        .text-wrapper {
          padding: 1rem;
          margin: 2rem;
        }
      }
    }

    .container {
      max-width: $website-width;
      margin: auto;
      padding: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .reverse {
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
```

```html
<section id="home-a">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- 1st Card -->
    <div class="card-container my-2">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="img/darts.jpg" alt="Darts" />
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h2>Darts</h2>
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam ab
          inventore ratione architecto velit labore quae consequatur minus
          rem incidunt.
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 2nd Card - Split -->
    <div class="card-container-split my-2">
      <div class="card-container-text">
        <div class="text-wrapper">
          <h2>Unsere Getränkekarte</h2>
          <h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam ab
            inventore ratione architecto velit labore quae consequatur minus
            rem incidunt.
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container-image">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="img/drinks.jpg" alt="Getränke" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 3rd Card - Split Reverse -->
    <div class="card-container-split my-2 reverse">
      <div class="card-container-text">
        <div class="text-wrapper">
          <h2>Reservierung</h2>
          <h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam ab
            inventore ratione architecto velit labore quae consequatur minus
            rem incidunt.
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-container-image">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img src="img/reserved.jpg" alt="Reservierung" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 4th Card Reverse -->
    <div class="card-container my-2 reverse">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="img/open.jpg" alt="Öffnungsschild" />
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h2>Öffnungszeiten</h2>
        <h3>
          Montag: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Dienstag: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Mittwoch: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Donnerstag: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Freitag: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Samstag: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
        <h3>
          Sonntag: 11:00 - 23:30 Uhr
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- 5th Card -->
    <div class="card-container my-2">
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h2>Covid 19</h2>
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam ab
          inventore ratione architecto velit labore quae consequatur minus
          rem incidunt.
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now i want color the background of these cards with alternating $main-color and $secondary-color. I used nth-child(4) to target the 4th card and change the background color but i cant find a way to target the 2 inner containers of the 3rd card to add margin and change the background color!

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp

I would recommend adding an ID to each card instead of relying on these classes that they share. It might look like this:

```
<div class="card-container my-2" id="FirstCard"></div>
<div class="card-container my-2" id="SecondCard"></div>
```

And so on...

Regardless, this should work:

```
/*3rd Slide Div 1*/
card-container-split:nth-child(2) card-container-text{
    /*your styling*/
}

/*3rd Slide Div 2*/
card-container-split:nth-child(2) card-container-image{
    /*your styling*/
}
```

If you decide to switch to using IDs, replace `card-container-split:nth-child(2)` with the ID for the third slide.

Comment: Avoid ID as css selector if possible. Not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

For altenate styling you can use :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even).
To select the 2 inner containers of the third you can use something like:

```
.container > :nth-child(3) > * {margin: 2rem; background-color: blue}
```

That will select all direct childs of the third element direct child of .container